# How does dfuse handle microforks?

Tags: dfuse

Sometimes, block producers eat blocks from one another, leading to small temporary forks on the chain.

How does dfuse handle that?

Answer (score 4):

Most commands (most notable `get_table_rows`), will send `step: "undo"` and `step: "redo"` messages, allowing you to stay in complete sync.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437994/how-to-effectively-stay-in-sync-when-using-dfuse-streaming-api